# How to decide dimensions and groups in dc.js?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am new to `dc.js` and facing issues in deciding dimensions and groups. I have data like this

```
this.data = [
    {Type:'Type1', Day:1, Count: 20},
    {Type:'Type2', Day:1, Count: 10},
    {Type:'Type1', Day:2, Count: 30},
    {Type:'Type2', Day:2, Count: 10}
]
```

I have to show a composite chart of two linecharts one for type Type1 and other for Type2. My x-axis will be Day. So one of my dimensions will be Day

```
var ndx = crossfilter(this.data);
var dayDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.Day; })
```

How the grouping will be done? If I do it on Count, the total count of a particular Day shows up which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but it sounds like you want to group by both `Type` and `Day`

One way to do it is to use composite keys:

```
var typeDayDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return [d.Type, d.Day]; }),
    typeDayGroup = typeDayDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.Count; });
```

Then you could use the series chart to generate two line charts inside a composite chart.

```
var chart = dc.seriesChart("#test");
chart
    .width(768)
    .height(480)
    .chart(function(c) { return dc.lineChart(c); })
    // ...
    .dimension(typeDayDimension)
    .group(typeDayGroup)
    .seriesAccessor(function(d) {return d.key[0];})
    .keyAccessor(function(d) {return +d.key[1];}) // convert to number
    // ...
```

See [the series chart example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/series.html) for more details.

Comment: Your solution works for me but can we do that by creating two lineCharts in a compositeChart?

Comment: That's what this does under the hood - the series chart is just a composite chart with automatic splitting of the data and generation of the child charts. If you want to do it manually, there are lots of ways... Too many ways. What's your objective?

Comment: Actually I am creating a generic method for creating lineCharts, so every time I will pass data, dimensions array and groups array to that method and it will create that number of lines in a chart. This is possible in composite chart as it expects array in `compose` and I have done that part. What I am not able to achieve is how can I create nested grouping of "Type" in "Day". I see I can use `.reduce` for that but not sure how to use that for nested groupings.

Comment: Never mind, I solved it myself. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Awesome! Yes a custom reduce function is probably the easiest way, although the composite key approach used by the series chart is also called. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Although what Gordon suggested is working perfectly fine, if you want to achieve the same result using composite chart then you can use [group.reduce(add, remove, initial)](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_reduce) method.

```
function reduceAdd(p, v) {
  if (v.Type === "Type1") {
    p.docCount += v.Count;
  } 
  return p;
}

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
  if (v.Type === "Type1") {
    p.docCount -= v.Count;
  } 
  return p;
}

function reduceInitial() {
  return { docCount: 0 };
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/curtisp/7frw79q6

Quoting [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704742/how-to-decide-dimensions-and-groups-in-dc-js/50848739#comment88661010_50717182):

> Series chart is just a composite chart with the automatic splitting of the data and generation of the child charts.