# dc.js charting nested data arrays

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

#### Problem description

I have a large data array with a structure similar to the following and seek to create a chart that will display the timerecords' changesets by hour that the changeset was created.

```
[ // array of records
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'some record',
        in_datetime: '2019-10-24T08:15:00.000000',
        out_datetime: '2019-10-24T10:15:00.000000',
        hours: 2,
        tasks: ["some task name", "another task"],
        changesets: [ //array of changesets within a record
            {
                id: 1001,
                created_at: '2019-10-24T09:37:00.000000'
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

No matter how I have tried to create the dimension/write reduction functions I can't get the correct values out of the data table.

```
const changeReduceAdd = (p, v) => {
    v.changesets.forEach(change => {
        let cHour = timeBand[change.created_hour]
        if (showByChanges) {
            p[cHour] = (p[cHour] || 0) + (change.num_changes || 0)
        } else {
            p[cHour] = (p[cHour] || 0) + 1 //this is 1 changeset
        }
    })
    return p
}

const changeReduceRemove = (p, v) => {
    v.changesets.forEach(change => {
        let cHour = timeBand[change.created_hour]
        if (showByChanges) {
            p[cHour] = (p[cHour] || 0) - (change.num_changes || 0)
        } else {
            p[cHour] = (p[cHour] || 0) - 1 //this is 1 changeset
        }
    })
    return p
}

const changeReduceInit = () => {
    return {}
}

//next create the array dimension of changesets by hour
//goal: show changesets or num_changes grouped by their created_hour
let changeDim = ndx.dimension(r => r.changesets.map(c => timeBand[c.created_hour]), true)
let changeGroup = changeDim.group().reduce(changeReduceAdd, changeReduceRemove, changeReduceInit)
let changeChart = dc.barChart('#changeset-hour-chart')
    .dimension(changeDim)
    .keyAccessor(d => d.key)
    .valueAccessor(d => d.value[d.key])
    .group(changeGroup)
```

[jsfiddle and debugging notes](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/5utLn8oz/4/)

The main problem I'm having is I want the changesets/created_hour chart, but in every dimension I have tried, where the keys appear correct, the values are significantly higher than the expected.

The values in the "8AM" category give value 5, when there are really only 3 changesets which I marked `created_hour: 8`:

[image: wrong histogram]

Comment: Your fiddle is using crossfilter version 1.3, which doesn't support tag dimensions. It works somewhat better with crossfilter 1.4: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/5utLn8oz/

Comment: Could you possibly edit your question to make it shorter? The NaN thing is not relevant and (with all due respect ;) it's also not very interesting to debug differences between your local and your fiddle. I'm not clear what the actual question is.

Comment: thanks the versioning was the difference between local/fiddle so that is taken out. sorry for the clutter. The fiddle was updated to use the new version, question simplified to show that it's the values in the changeset/hour table that is the problem and returning unexpected values

Comment: Good question, thanks. I'm looking into it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of solutions to the "tag dimension" problem, and you happen to have chosen two of the best.

Either

1. the custom reduction, or
2. the array/tag flag parameter to the dimension constructor

would do the trick.

Combining the two techniques is what got you into trouble. I didn't try to figure what exactly was going on, but you were somehow summing the counts of the hours.

#### Simple solution: use the built-in tag dimension feature

Use the tag/dimension flag and default `reduceCount`:

```
let changeDim = ndx.dimension(r => r.changesets.map(c => timeBand[c.created_hour]), true)
let changeGroup = changeDim.group(); // no reduce, defaults to reduceCount
let changeChart = dc.barChart('#changeset-hour-chart')
    .dimension(changeDim)
    .keyAccessor(d => d.key)
    .valueAccessor(d => d.value) // no [d.key], value is count
    .group(changeGroup)
```

[image: correct histogram]

[fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/5utLn8oz/3/)

#### Manual, pre-1.4 groupAll version

You also have a **groupAll** solution in your code. This solution was necessary before array/tag dimensions were introduced in crossfilter 1.4.

Out of curiosity, I tried enabling it, and it also works once you transform from the groupAll result into group results:

```
function groupall_map_to_group(groupall) {
  return {
    all: () => Object.entries(groupall.value())
                     .map(([key,value])=>({key,value}))
  }
}

let changeGroup = ndx.groupAll().reduce(changeReduceAdd, changeReduceRemove, changeReduceInit)
let changeChart = dc.barChart('#changeset-hour-chart')
    .dimension({}) // filtering not implemented
    .keyAccessor(d => d.key)
    .valueAccessor(d => d.value) // [d.key]
    .group(groupall_map_to_group(changeGroup))
    .x(dc.d3.scaleBand().domain(timeBand))
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticY(true)
    .render()
```

[crossfilter 1.3 version](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/uhek6y41/6/)

Comment: Wow that's interesting, I did not expect the tag dimension to simply work like that. Is there an easy way to sum the `num_changes` for the changesets in that bin?

Comment: I don’t see `num_changes` in your data set. Do you man doing a `reduceSum` on `changesets.length`?

Comment: `num_changes` is a property of the changesets

Comment: [reduceSum documentation](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_reduceSum)

Comment: since it's a nested property within the timerecord reduceSum gets called for each timerecord for every changeset that it has. is there a way for the reduceSum to know what key it is calculating for so I could reduce it something like
`.group().reduceSum(d => {
 return d.changesets.reduce((acc, c) => {
  if(c.created_hour matches the group's key) {
   return acc + c.num_changes
  } else {
   return acc
  }
 })
})`

Comment: See the second part of this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58135255/676195